# how i can i solve no module named can error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, can-bus

hello i'm using python 3 and ros noetic,  and i got this error

```
import can
ImportError: No module named can
```

I've got this error before, and I solved it through a very simple can-bus related installation command in google.  But I can't find that command now
I've tried all the like `$ sudo apt install python3-can`.
but I can't fix it at all

thank you................

Comment: $ pip install python-can or $ pip3 install python-can

Comment: This for merely python 3.7

Comment: thanks for replying but i tried all that things but i got ```Requirement already satisfied: python-can in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: aenum in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-can) (3.1.11)```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Here is link https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/installation.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. I'm Linux and I use Kvaser, but what's out there doesn't work 

Comment: i remembered that command is very simple and includes like 'can-bus' words Do you have any idea?

Comment: you can run "pip freeze" command to verify all of your installed modules.

Comment: How do you start you python interpreter? `pyhton`, `python3`, ...?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the module can't be found by your python.

first, try to remove the package with:

```
pip uninstall python-can
```

and re-install it with

```
pip install python-can
```

In case you have several versions of python installed (such as python2 and python3) make sure, you use

```
pip3
```

instead of pip.

Next you can try to manually search your package directories for the package, if it is even there.

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning the library with git and running the setup.py installation, worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).